# How to obtain the path name of train_dataset after using random_split in torch

Tags: python, pytorch

I have the following code:

```
import torch, torchvision
root_dataset ="./data"
dataset = torchvision.datasets.folder.ImageFolder(root=root_dataset, transform=None, target_transform=None)
train_dataset, valid_dataset = torch.utils.data.dataset.random_split(
    dataset=dataset,
    lengths=[num_train, num_valid]
)
```

My question is:

How can I obtain the name list of the path of `train_dataset` after using `random_split` in `torch`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paths (and labels) are stored in `dataset.imgs`. For instance, for imagenet:

```py
In [ ]: print(dataset.imgs[0])
Out [ ]: ('/shareDB/imagenet/val/n01440764/ILSVRC2012_val_00000293.JPEG', 0)
```

After splitting the dataset, each split points to the *original* dataset:

```py
In [ ]: len(train_dataset.dataset), len(valid_dataset.dataset)
Out [ ]: (50000, 50000)
```

However, each split also holds the indices of samples from the original dataset selected for the split. You can use these indices and the original dataset to get a list of the images selected for each split:

```py
valid_imgs = [valid_dataset.dataset.imgs[i_] for i_ in valid_dataset.indices]
train_imgs = [train_dataset.dataset.imgs[i_] for i_ in train_dataset.indices]
```